# TextToSpeech throwing an unknown exception

Tags: java, android, exception, text-to-speech

I am creating an android app involving text messaging with one feature being that each letter is read out when entered. I am using **TextToSpeech**.

I have it working in a test project however when integrating it into my own i receive an *unknown exception*.

can anyone see what could be causing this and suggest a remedy? I have created a class called speech which is instantiated in another class and has a method which calls speak out (Similar to second example below.) Also can anyone explain why I need to extend Activity on the first example? The same problematic line says that **"new TextToSpeech is not defined"**.

Snippet where will not work. error is on `tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);`

```
public class Speech extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private String toRead;

    public Speech(String toRead){

        this.toRead = toRead;
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }
```

Here is the code for where it does work

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private Button btnSpeak;
    private EditText txtText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

        btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);

        txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

        // button on click event
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speakOut();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

    private void speakOut() {

        String text = txtText.getText().toString();

        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

Logcat info

```
02-13 20:00:54.974: D/AndroidRuntime(11127): Shutting down VM
02-13 20:00:54.974: W/dalvikvm(11127): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411cd300)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.BT/org.BT.Text_entry}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:91)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.speech.tts.TtsEngines.getDefaultEngine(TtsEngines.java:75)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.getDefaultEngine(TextToSpeech.java:1235)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:595)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:553)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:527)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:512)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at org.BT.Speech.<init>(Speech.java:17)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at org.BT.Text_entry.<init>(Text_entry.java:48)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
02-13 20:00:54.979: E/AndroidRuntime(11127):    ... 11 more
```

-----------------------------------------edit-------------------------------------------------------
further research has suggested that it may be because I am trying Android framework outside of an android context? Could this be true - because I am using a class and not an activity? If so how would i get around this?

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace log? That would give a better idea.

Comment: Have posted Logcat info... is this what you needed?

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me as the standard example of TextToSpeech (TTS) that can be found on the internet everywhere and it should work as such without any problem.  (However, this doesn't mean that there is no any design problem with this example of code.)

Maybe the version of Android that you are using is too old or that the TTS has not been set up correctly on your phone?  Did you check the setting for TTS on your phone?  (Normally, if the TTS has not been set up correctly on your phone, this code should call the proper installation page to do it but I remember seeing one message that this part can sometimes bomb out.)

You should also check that `txtText` is not null after its initialisation with `findViewById()`.

Comment: Essentially it is. That version works perfectly however it is the first code snippet - where I am trying to use it in a standard java class that the problem lies

Comment: Are you using this on an Android system or on something else?

Comment: It is being created as an android application and being run on an android phone and on the emulator. The standard TTS (snippet 2) works 100% fine - It's just when putting it in a standard class (snippet 1) that the problem occurs

Comment: Well, excerpt for a very short snippet of a few lines, you don't really show us the code that doesn't work; so what are you expecting from us?  However, from these few lines, I can see that you have had the bad idea of putting the creation of a very complex object like the TextToSpeech class directly into the Speech constructor instead of doing this in the onCreate() callback or when the speech function is first called. What's possibly happening here is that the base context for the Activity is probably not yet fully initialised when the TextToSpeech object need it.

Answer (score 0):

That is how i do it..

```
public class TextToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
{
private TextToSpeech mTts;
// This code can be any value you want, its just a checksum.
private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 1234;

/**
* Called when the activity is first created.
*/
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

// Fire off an intent to check if a TTS engine is installed
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

}

public void speakClicked(View v)
{
// grab the contents of the text box.
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);

mTts.speak(editText.getText().toString(),TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

public void onInit(int i)
{

}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE)
{
if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS)
{
// success, create the TTS instance
mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
}
else
{
// missing data, install it
Intent installIntent = new Intent();
installIntent.setAction(
TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
startActivity(installIntent);
}
}
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
if (mTts != null)
{
mTts.stop();
mTts.shutdown();
}
super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this change the screen? I only wan't the speech class as a support class which can be instantiated in my main class and just have a public method called which will perform the speech instructions